# Java encryption frameworks/toolkits

Tags: java, encryption

My team is looking for a proven and easy to use Java encryption framework or toolkit to encrypt our data traffic.  We have found Google's [KeyCzar](http://www.keyczar.org/) and it looks promising but we want to know if anyone has had success with other toolkits or have had issues with KeyCzar.

Comment: How secured do you want your traffic to be? In addition, do you want encryption with the help of keys or something like that or just simple data encoding? Even more, why do you need to do this yourself? Many ready-to-use online protocols support data encoding. Even Java itself has some support for it!

Comment: As the KeyCzar page states, "Cryptography is easy to get wrong."  The team has little experience with encryption and want to get off to a good start.  We expect to use public/private keys but are open to suggestions.

Comment: When you say "our data traffic", is it for transport-level or message-level encryption? Why not use TLS if it's for transport-level encryption?

Answer (score 2):

I have succesfully used [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/), pretty easy to get started.

Comment: that was the best , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK comes with a security framework and encryption algorithms.
Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html.